# How do I find the input field that I left from after enter pressed that submits a form.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three input field in HTML. If I enter something in the second field, and press enter, error function is triggered. I want to highlight the second field which triggered error function on enter. 
How do I capture the second input field that triggered error function?

Pressing enter key is not handled, but automatically presses submit button.

Comment: Could you provide the code that you're currently working with?

Comment: @MatthewW. Sorry. There is not much code to show. It's just 3 input fields and 1 submit button. When I say error function, it's not relevant to on enter/keypress event. Error function is attached to each input fields, checks condition and triggers error message if not satisfied.

Comment: You should add an onSubmit event handler that returns false when there is and error. In that event handler you can set focus and select text on the offending textbox

Comment: @Bindrid After making it into onSubmit event, how can I find the input field that I left from?(before enter being pressed)

Comment: Looks like Dkellner covered it. The only thing I would add is that if you include the event obj in the function, you can get at all the details to what caused it.  so his code below would look like $("input").on("change",function(evt){} and so on. evt.target is usually the client control that triggered the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is probably one of two things:

**1. A value check whenever the field value has *changed*.**
For this, you have the onChange event which you can manage like this:

```
$("input").on("change",function() {
    var field = $(this);
    // field.val() is the value
    // field.attr("name") is the name of your input element
    errorCheck(field); // your error checker
});
```

**2. A value check when the form is being *submitted*.**
To do this, you'll have to *remember* which input was last focused.  Attach onFocus event to your inputs:

```
var lastFocused = 0;
$("input").on("focus",function() { lastFocused = $(this); });
$("form").on("submit",function() {
    // now you have the value in lastFocused.val()
    // lastFocused itself is a jQuery object of the field
    errorCheck(lastFocused); // this is your own error checker of course
});
```

Now you can check the value no matter how the user submits a form (e.g. pressing enter).

**Note** that the first method (onChange) will also happen when submitting the form; it happens when the focus leaves a field that has been modified since focused.  Therefore, when you enter something and submit, you'll get both a *submit* and a *change* event.  (Not sure which one first.)

**Also note** that you'll have to deal with stopping the form submission if you have errors - otherwise (in a postback situation) the page will reload or change and all what's entered will be gone with the wind.  Ajax submits are a good option to deal with this matter.  (Iframes are another, just not very modern.)

If this was not the answer, let's refine the question :)